# Mysql update table using webpy

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I want the below query to implement in webpy using db.update

```
  update emp set age=age+1 where x=1`
```

When i tried

```
 db.update('emp',where='x=1',age=age+1)
```

This throw me an error saying global name 'age' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `db.query` instead,like this 
`results = db.query("UPDATE emp SET age=age+1 WHERE x=$x", vars={'x':1})`

Comment: Thanks man. I had figure that out long back, but still there will be people like me. For future use ;)